# how to stop rendering twice (for non-data retrieving components) when using prerendering from _host.cshtml in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, server-side-rendering, blazor-webassembly, preloading

I have some variables that initialize in the code segment in a razor page and they are initializing twice when I started doing the prerendering from the server using _Host.cshtml in the application. How can I avoid these initializations during the second render from the client part loading in UI?

```
public string isVisible="hidden";
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    if (firstRender)
    {
        isVisible = "visible";
    }
}
```

This variable is going back to the value "hidden" in the second rendering. Please help how can this be prevented.

Answer (score 4):

From the following site:
[Stateful reconnection after prerendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#stateful-reconnection-after-prerendering)

In a Blazor Server app when RenderMode is ServerPrerendered, the component is initially rendered statically as part of the page. Once the browser establishes a SignalR connection back to the server, the component is rendered again and interactive. If the OnInitialized{Async} lifecycle method for initializing the component is present, the method is executed twice:

When the component is prerendered statically.
After the server connection has been established.
This can result in a noticeable change in the data displayed in the UI when the component is finally rendered. To avoid this double-rendering behavior in a Blazor Server app, pass in an identifier to cache the state during prerendering and to retrieve the state after prerendering.

The following code demonstrates an updated WeatherForecastService in a template-based Blazor Server app that avoids the double rendering. In the following example, the awaited Delay (await Task.Delay(...)) simulates a short delay before returning data from the GetForecastAsync method.

WeatherForecastService.cs

```c#
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using BlazorSample.Shared;

public class WeatherForecastService
{
    private static readonly string[] summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild",
        "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    public WeatherForecastService(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        MemoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public IMemoryCache MemoryCache { get; }

    public Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetForecastAsync(DateTime startDate)
    {
        return MemoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync(startDate, async e =>
        {
            e.SetOptions(new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
            {
                AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow =
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
            });

            var rng = new Random();

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = summaries[rng.Next(summaries.Length)]
            }).ToArray();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please help me in using this for a non-task returning service?

Comment: @Keerthi, please post an example method from the service you are working on.

Comment: Hi @Jason, I posted my code as an answer in the following(to let the code look properly indented). Kindly take a look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="page_body">
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar_cs">
        <NavMenu Width="@ScreenWidth" />
    </div>
    <div style="visibility:@isVisible">
        <CarouselBlock imageset="@CDNImages" />
        @Body
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <FooterMenu />
    </div>
</div>
```

the above code is in the Html segment of the MainLayout.razor file and the following in the code segment.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject BrowserService Service
@inject CarouselService cs

public int ScreenWidth { get; set; }
private List<string> CDNImages;
 protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();
    try
    {
        isVisible = "visible";
        ScreenWidth = Service.GetDimension().Width;
        Console.WriteLine("initializing");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error occurred " + e.ToString());
    }
}
protected override void OnParametersSet()
{
    base.OnParametersSet();
    CDNImages = cs.GetImages();
    Console.WriteLine("images are set in onParameterSet");
    //   isVisible = "visible";
}

protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    if (firstRender)
    {
        //  isVisible = "visible";
    }
}
```

The method in CarouselService.cs is the following and it provides the string list to the CarouselBlock component.

```
 public List<string> GetImages() 
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            paths.Add(FolderPath + Province + "/test" + i + ".png");
        }
        return paths;
    }
```

This is my entire code for the landing page in the application and all I want is to prevent the page from re-rendering as I'm already using _Host.cshtml to pre-render from the server.

this is the reference that I used for pre-rendering:
[page link](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/general/how-do-i-prerender-a-blazor-webassembly-application-to-static-files)

Please let me know how can I prevent the flickering effect of the page when the refresh button is clicked in the browser.